# Installation of the couchdb in the iphone device

Tags: couchdb

I am planning to use the couchdb in my iphone application . Please tell me how to install the couchdb in my iphone device . I googled , but i didnt get any good link.

swathi.

Answer (score 1):

[TouchDB](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS) is a "CouchDB-compatible" data store.

It is written in Objective C, so it can be included in iOS applications, and it's able to replicate with other CouchDB/Couchbase instances. (in addition, it's API is *very similar*, but not identical)

Answer (score 0):

The new version of TouchDB is [Couchbase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios), which also runs on MacOS and .Net, which is kinda useful.